# Subclassing a python class with optional arguments

Tags: python

I am new to Python. I have this code:

```
class SomeClass(OtherClass):
    name = "whatever"
    task = "nothing"
```

Now, I want to create a child class such that, I am able to instantiate it like this:

```
child = ChildClass(task = "sometask")
child.name #=> "whatever"
child.task #=> "sometask"
child2 = ChildClass()
child2.task #=> "nothing"
```

How can I do that?

Comment: You mean those URLs are kind of static data?

Answer (score 3):

First, you need to note that you are creating class variables in `SomeClass`, not instance variables

```
class SomeClass(object):
    def __init__(self, name = "whatever", task = "nothing"):
        self.name = name
        self.task = task
```

Now we have designed a class, which accepts two keyword arguments with default values. So, if you don't pass values to any of them, by default `whatever` will be assigned to `name` and `nothing` will be assigned to `task`.

```
class ChildClass(SomeClass):
    def __init__(self, name = "whatever", task = "nothing"):
        super(ChildClass, self).__init__(name, task)

child1 = ChildClass(task = "sometask")
print child1.name, child1.task
# whatever sometask
child2 = ChildClass()
print child2.name, child2.task
# whatever nothing
```

Comment: @Stoic Indeed, if it is a new style class :)

Comment: [super](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#super) (Python 2), [super](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#super) (Python 3)

Comment: alright, and I noticed that you called super on the class itself, and not the method? Is there a way to call the parent method without referencing `super(ChildClass, self)`? What I mean is I cannot I say: `super(name, task)` inside the child's `__init__` ?

Comment: @Stoic In Python 2.x, that is how you should do. But in Python 3, you can simply do `super().__init__(..)`. Please check the links given by Two-bit-Alchemist.

Answer (score 1):

You need to overwrite its **initializer** (sort of like a constructor in other languages):

```
>>> class SomeClass:
...   name='whatever'
...   task='nothing'
...
>>> class ChildClass(SomeClass):
...   def __init__(self, name=None, task=None):
...     if name is not None:
...       self.name = name
...     if task is not None:
...       self.task = task
...
>>> child = ChildClass(task='sometask')
>>> child.name
'whatever'
>>> child.task
'sometask'
>>> child2 = ChildClass()
>>> child2.task
'nothing'
```